# WPF textbox bound to datetime string format not working when using converters

Tags: wpf, textbox, type-conversion

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentGameDate,Mode=OneWay,    
Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter},     
StringFormat='{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}" />
```

string format doesnt seem to work.

i want only the date.
i've tried `stringformat=d`

Comment: I dont want to change the converter as it is being used in other places

Comment: stringformat works on only strings. what is the return type you are returning from converter?

Comment: the converter returns a string

Comment: public static string Convert(object value)
        {
            if (value is DateTime)
            {
                return ((DateTime)value).ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }
            return null;
        }

Comment: this should have worked. what do you see on the textbox, the entire date with time?

Comment: entire date with time.. not able to remove time

Comment: ok i was wrong..it doesn't work on strings..try returning DateTime from the converter instead of a string.

Comment: thanks .. it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String Format for dates works on variables of type DateTime only. So, you should return a DateTime instead of string from the converter.